# How to handle classCastException

Tags: java, exception

Can not we convert a string object to a byte object?

```
public bitmap a(String s){
   byte[] b=(byte[])getValue(s);
   ...
}
```

`getValue` returns a string object.

Comment: Casting references does not convert the objects referenced.  You can only cast a reference if the object is this type already. If you want to convert the object you need to call a method which performs the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String.getBytes()` and its overloaded versions to transform a `String` to `byte[]`.

There are overloaded versions that allow you to specify the charset like UTF-8 for instance:

```
getBytes(String charsetName);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the no-arguments version at all, you *almost always* want to specify an encoding (and UTF-8 is the most likely candidate).

Comment: Sure, but getBytes() is a first great step from the OP's version.